# How to make string of specified length from another string c#

Tags: c#, string, string-length

For example I have strings like:

> "5", "8", "14", "260"

and I want to get result like:

> "ST00000005", "ST00000008", "ST00000014", "ST00000260"

result string length is 10 chars. How can I do it?

Comment: What you already tried?

Comment: Something like adding "TS", after it adding "0" until string.lenght will be 10. But It doesn't work correctly for me, so I want to find another (may be better) solution.

Comment: I think you dont get "-2" if you show your code and where problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would store it as `int` not as string. Then you can use [`ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t7dwaa5(v=vs.110).aspx) with the appropriate format specifier `D8`. That has f.e. the advantage that you can increase the number:

```
int number = 5;
string result = String.Format("ST{0}", number.ToString("D8"));
```

or without `ToString` but only [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string result = String.Format("ST{0:D8}", number);
```

Read: [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.100).aspx) especially [Decimal ("D") Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.100).aspx#DFormatString)

If you need to convert a string to `int` use [`int.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) or `int.TryParse`.

For the sake of completeness, if you have to use strings use [`String.PadLeft(8, '0')`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.padleft(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string numStr = "5";
String result = String.Format("ST{0}", numStr.PadLeft(8, '0'));
```

Comment: You always comes up with something exciting. Lot of learnings from your post.

Comment: Please check my answer @Tim, cause I think thats the fancier way in C#6

Comment: @RajeevKumar its even more exciting if you use string interpolation

Comment: @Mafii: i've yet not the possibility to check C#6 features like string interpolation.

Comment: @Mafii C#6.0 is still very new. it need some time to get used to with developers across the world

Comment: @TimSchmelter if your curios, check my answer. It internally translates to `String.Format` so your answer is in no way worse or different. :)

Comment: @RajeevKumar yes, but it has some really nice semantic advantages, like Get-Only properties with backing fields and string interpolation.

Comment: Even with old C# you can use ´{0:D8}´

Answer (score 1):

```
int number = 5; // put the number here

string result = $"ST{number:0000000#}";

// Or:

string result = $"ST{number:D8}";
```

This does exactly what you want.

EDIT: Keep in mind that this is only possible in C#6

Comment: You should mention that it's a C#6 feature called string interpolation. However +1

Comment: @TimSchmelter ty, added.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like

```
string s = "215";
s = s.PadLeft(8, '0').PadLeft(9,'T').PadLeft(10,'S');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [string.Format()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) together with a [custom format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) string.